# Kendo headerTemplate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to build this dojo with the headerTemplate and the columns title and data fields under it but I am not sure what I am doing wrong I am not getting any errors so its hard to understand what is happening?

[image]

https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevittnccn/iNinebUm

Comment: The JavaScript console says: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after function body. note: { opened at line 24, column 18

Comment: not sure where that line is?

Comment: I Valided the JSON string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a bit different approach here. Problem is that your data is a complex nested object (an object with an array of objects - basically grid inside grid). Kendo data source best works with flattened data. If you can't change data you can use the kendo grid [detailInit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/detailinit) event so every object array has an inner table with data. Something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kendogrid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        data: data,
        pageSize: 10
      },
      pageable: true,
      scrollable: false,
      persistSelection: true,
      toolbar: ["search"],
      search: {
        fields: ['Name']
      },
      sortable: true,
      columns: [
        {
          field: "Name",
          title: "Name"
        }
      ],
      detailTemplate: '<div class="grid"></div>',
      detailInit: function (e) {
        e.detailRow.find(".grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: e.data.PanelsMeetingViewModel
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Example: [Kendo grid detail init](https://dojo.telerik.com/acAmemaD)

Note: because of the inner table quick search will not work.

Comment: @dev-in-progress if I flattened data would I be able to use a search and have a title with columns header?

Comment: Yea it would be possible but complex. If you have a lot of data it would be suggested server filtering. Or you can do something like this: https://dojo.telerik.com/oWiwAkEm

Comment: Any way to remove that top name row?

Comment: Sorry last question any way to remove the collapse button and center the title?